# Returning to Origin city when Married

Tags: tales-of-arabian-nights

**Do you need to end your turn in the city with your origin marker in order to satisfy the condition on the *Married* status?**

The status *Married* says, in part:

> After you have an encounter in another city, you must return to your home before you may end your turn in any other cities.

It is ambiguous as to whether or not you must end your turn in this home city in order for it to count, or if you may simply move over it with your movement (rolling your check for making babies on the way) and then proceed as normal.

On the one hand, nothing else in the game functions by just passing over a space, but on the other, many cards make reference to their effects happening only "after an encounter," while this one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must end a turn in your origin city before you may end your turn in any other. Your interpretation is correct, this game does not care about the spaces you pass over as you move (aside from the movement speed, though that's between spaces technically), only the spaces you end your turn on.

Answer (score -1):

"End your turn in any other cities" defines return as ending your turn in your home. Otherwise, it would say "end your turn in a city". This is standard English and board gaming terminology. None of the roughly fifteen people with whom I've played ever suggested otherwise.

Comment: Players that I have played disagree with you - they have argued that you do not have to end your turn to gain the effect as it does not say that an encounter is required (as it normally would).  They also argue that, subjectively, the penalty to the effect would be too great if you did have to spend an entire turn there.  Do you have any more substantial evidence?

Comment: @SouthpawHare, ikegami - I've cleaned up this thread. Both positions have been stated. The votes can decide now.